# Running a shell script using "sh script.sh" or "./script.sh" gives two different outcomes?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm having trouble understanding how my Ubuntu unix environment handles script execution. I wrote the following bash script (called `script.sh`) to show my confusion:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ $1 == "yes" ]; then
    echo -ne "Caught\n"
fi
if [ $1 != "yes" ]; then
    echo -ne "Not Caught\n"
fi
```

When I execute this script using `sh script.sh yes`, I get the following output:

```
`tester.sh: 2: [: yes: unexpected operator`
```

However, when I use `chmod 775 script.sh` to make the script executable and then use the command `./script.sh yes`, I get the appropriate output of `Caught`.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I want the script to execute correctly whether I use the `sh` or the `./` method.

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: `sh` in modern versions of Ubuntu is `dash`, not `bash`.  When you execute with `sh` you are using `dash` and when you execute as `./script.sh` you are using `bash`.

Comment: Is there anyway to change my shebang line or something to make sure that `sh` will use bash? I want to release a script that other people on different machines will use, and I need the script to always execute in `bash`

Comment: @jake9115 no, `sh` is `sh`, not `bash`. On some systems `sh` is a symlink to `bash`, but even then, bash behaves differently when invoked as `sh` than it does when invoked as `bash`.

Comment: Nope.  You could change the default `sh` to `bash` however.  But I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Can I use `bash script.sh` to ensure people use bash if they aren't using the `./` method? Is `bash script.sh` a valid command on different flavors of linux?

Comment: Yes you can and yes it is.

Comment: `case "$0" in sh*) printf 'Please run this as ./%s\n.' "$1"; exit 1;; esac;`

Comment: oooo, i like that one

Comment: derp. please see edited comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sh ...` will run your script using shell, not bash... for your script to use what's specified in the shabang, first make your script executable then run it using `./script.sh`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a single `=` instead of `==` which is a bashism, i.e. not standard.

So when you run ./script.sh `bash` interprets your script and it's all fine. When you run `sh script.sh` a different program does this (maybe old bourne sh, dash or even `bash` in disguise*).

> I want the script to execute correctly whether I use the sh or the ./
>   method.

Then don't rely on non-portable features such as `==`.

---

- By `bash` in disguise I mean that `bash` pays attention to argv[0] - the way you call it - and acts accordingly. If you call it `sh` (perhaps using a link) then it tries to behave like the Bourne shell does.

Comment: How about `shellism`, is there such a thing?

Comment: @l'L'l There is POSIX, specifying how `test` should behave.